# Python - Creating a for loop to build a single csv file with multiple dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am new to python and trying various things to learn the fundamentals.  One of the things that i'm currently stuck on is for loops.  I have the following code and am positive it can be built out more efficiently using a loop but i'm not sure exactly how.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url1 = 'https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/stats/player/receiving/nfl/regular/qualifiers/?page=1'
url2 = 'https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/stats/player/receiving/nfl/regular/qualifiers/?page=2'
url3 = 'https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/stats/player/receiving/nfl/regular/qualifiers/?page=3'

df1 = pd.read_html(url1)
df1[0].to_csv ('NFL_Receiving_Page1.csv', index=False) #index false gets rid of index listing that appears as the very first column in the csv

df2 = pd.read_html(url2)
df2[0].to_csv ('NFL_Receiving_Page2.csv', index=False) #index false gets rid of index listing that appears as the very first column in the csv

df3 = pd.read_html(url3)
df3[0].to_csv ('NFL_Receiving_Page3.csv', index=False) #index false gets rid of index listing that appears as the very first column in the csv

df_receiving_agg = pd.concat([df1[0], df2[0], df3[0]])
df_receiving_agg.to_csv('NFL_Receiving_Combined.csv', index=False) #index false gets rid of index listing that appears as the very first column in the csv
```

I'm ultimately trying to combine the data in the above URL's into a single table in a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
urls = [url1,url2,url3]
df_receiving_agg = pd.DataFrame()
for url in urls:
    df = pd.read_html(url)
    df_receiving_agg = pd.concat([df_receiving_agg, df])
df_receiving_agg.to_csv('filepath.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
base_url = 'https://www.cbssports.com/nfl/stats/player/receiving/nfl/regular/qualifiers/?page='
dfs = []
for page in range(1, 4):
    url = f'{base_url}{page}'
    df = pd.read_html(url)
    df.to_csv(f'NFL_Receiving_Page{page}.csv', index=False)
    dfs.append(df)

df_receiving_agg = pd.concat(dfs)
df_receiving_agg.to_csv('NFL_Receiving_Combined.csv', index=False)
```